# dismiss ViewController and dismiss keyboard not working together

Tags: ios, xib, viewcontroller

I have the following XIB file presented (.custom) when a button is pressed.

```
@IBAction func contactUsBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            let contactUs = ContactUsXIB()
            contactUs.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
            present(contactUs, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
```

[image]
You'll notice in the top right corner there is a close button.
I have assigned the following code to this button:

```
@IBAction func closeBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

This works fine.

For each of the UITextFields, I want the keyboard to dismiss if the user taps anywhere else on the screen.
I implemented this code in the swift file to do so: (this dismiss keyboard/view.endEditing(true) code has worked many times for me in other apps)

```
import UIKit

class ContactUsXIB: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var telephoneField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()

    }

    @IBAction func closeBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    func setupView() {
        let tap: UIGestureRecognizer = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ContactUsXIB.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)     
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)  
    }
}
```

However when I implement this feature, the close button does not work nor does the dismiss keyboard.
Here is the incorrect behaviour I now have:

1. XIB is presented, tap close button - No response

   tap a text field - XIB is dismissed
2. XIB is presented

   tap a text field, tap anywhere else to dismiss keyboard - no
   response

   tap close button - no response

   tap a text field - XIB is dismissed

Any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Suresh! This worked perfectly.
Is this method better than setting a UIGestureRecognizer etc? It's certainly less code!